# Automatically generated table of contents

Tags: html, tableofcontents

I am trying to have auto-generated table of contents in HTML.

I take inputs in the page and as I take HTML page is updated so it can show the input it take

How can I do that without using JavaScript?

Comment: You can't do this without some sort of dynamic script. HTML is just a static language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot generate things automatically in HTML. You would have to do the generation using a preprocessor, or a server-side tool, or with client-side JavaScript.

The best you can do in HTML to *allow* browsers or their add-ons to generate a table of contents is to use heading elements `h1`, `h2` etc. consistently, according to the logical nesting level. This is what ToC generators such as the Firefox [Table of Contents add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/fi/firefox/addon/table-of-contents/?src=api) use as data.